# Entities not persisting. Are RepositoryItemWriter & SimpleJpaWriter thread-safe?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

I have encountered an odd issue with a RepositoryItemWriter, where it does not appear to be persisting entities correctly through my configured Spring Data JPA repository to the data source.

Step configuration

```
@Bean
public Step orderStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<OrderEncounter> orderEncounterReader, ItemWriter<List<Order>> orderWriter,
                      ItemProcessor<OrderEncounter, List<Order>> orderProcessor, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("orderStep")
            .<OrderEncounter, List<Order>> chunk(10)
            .reader(orderEncounterReader)
            .processor(orderProcessor)
            .writer(orderWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
}
```

Task Executor Bean (configured for 1 thread for testing purposes)

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

OrderRepository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long> {

}
```

orderWriter bean

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<List<Order>> orderWriter(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    RepositoryListItemWriter<List<Order>> writer = new RepositoryListItemWriter<>();
    writer.setRepository(orderRepository);
    writer.setMethodName("save");

    try {
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return writer;
}
```

RepositoryListItemWriter (modified RepositoryItemWriter to support multiple items that are returned from a stored procedure result set)

```
public class RepositoryListItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, InitializingBean {
    protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(RepositoryListItemWriter.class);
    private CrudRepository<?, ?> repository;
    private String methodName;

    public RepositoryListItemWriter() {
    }

    public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    public void setRepository(CrudRepository<?, ?> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(items)) {
            this.doWrite(items);
        }

    }

    protected void doWrite(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Writing to the repository with " + items.size() + " items.");
        }

        MethodInvoker invoker = this.createMethodInvoker(this.repository, this.methodName);
        Iterator i$ = items.iterator();

        while(i$.hasNext()) {
            Object object = i$.next();
            invoker.setArguments(new Object[]{object});
            this.doInvoke(invoker);
        }

    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.state(this.repository != null, "A CrudRepository implementation is required");
    }

    private Object doInvoke(MethodInvoker invoker) throws Exception {
        try {
            invoker.prepare();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var3) {
            throw new DynamicMethodInvocationException(var3);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException var4) {
            throw new DynamicMethodInvocationException(var4);
        }

        try {
            return invoker.invoke();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException var5) {
            if(var5.getCause() instanceof Exception) {
                throw (Exception)var5.getCause();
            } else {
                throw new InvocationTargetThrowableWrapper(var5.getCause());
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException var6) {
            throw new DynamicMethodInvocationException(var6);
        }
    }

    private MethodInvoker createMethodInvoker(Object targetObject, String targetMethod) {
        MethodInvoker invoker = new MethodInvoker();
        invoker.setTargetObject(targetObject);
        invoker.setTargetMethod(targetMethod);
        return invoker;
    }
}
```

When orderStep is configured without a taskExecutor, then entities persist fine through the RepositoryItemWriter to the database; however, when it is configured with even a single-threaded taskExecutor, nothing is persisted to the database throughout the entire job execution - including after completion.

I've performed a considerable amount of research and RepositoryItemWriter appears to be thread-safe -- along with PagingAndSortingRepository & SimpleJpaWriter. Any suggestions?

Trace-level log output

No TaskExecutor in job:

```
2015-11-23 20:51:07.589 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults     : Found bean property 'verified
ChangedByUsername' of type [java.lang.String]2015-11-23 20:51:07.589 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springfr
amework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@56ca0bbc] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@5ffffca4] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-1]2015-11-23 20:51:07.590 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Transient instance of: com.ii
massociates.distiller.domain.Order2015-11-23 20:51:07.590 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2015-11-23 20:51:07.590 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<null>]
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order] object
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Executing inserts before finding non-nullable transient entities for early insert: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<null>]
]
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<null>]]
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Executing insertions before resolved early-insert
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 DEBUG 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Executing identity-insert immediately
2015-11-23 20:51:07.591 TRACE 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Inserting entity: com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order (native id)
2015-11-23 20:51:07.592 DEBUG 31126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into orders (blah blah SQL)
```

TaskExecutor in job

```
2015-11-23 21:02:34.628 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults     : Found bean property 'verifiedChangedByUsername' of type [java.lang.String]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.628 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2b151d8a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@2706e09c] bound to thread [taskExecutor-1]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.629 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Transient instance of: com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order
2015-11-23 21:02:34.629 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2015-11-23 21:02:34.629 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<null>]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order] object
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<delayed:1>]]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding resolved non-early insert action.
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<delayed:1>]]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2b151d8a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@2706e09c] bound to thread [taskExecutor-1]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Transient instance of: com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2015-11-23 21:02:34.630 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<null>]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.631 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order] object
2015-11-23 21:02:34.631 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.Order#<delayed:2>]]
2015-11-23 21:02:34.631 TRACE 31257 --- [ taskExecutor-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding resolved non-early insert action.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I fixed it by adding a PlatformTransactionManager. See changes below. Hope this helps someone, as this is one that I've been fighting for a couple of weeks now. What I don't understand is why Spring Boot is able to provide a JtaTransactionManager w/o Bitronix or Atomikos in my pom.xml.

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Bean
public Step orderStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<OrderEncounter> orderEncounterReader, ItemWriter<List<Order>> orderWriter,
                      ItemProcessor<OrderEncounter, List<Order>> orderProcessor, TaskExecutor taskExecutor, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("orderStep")
            .<OrderEncounter, List<Order>> chunk(10)
            .reader(orderEncounterReader)
            .processor(orderProcessor)
            .writer(orderWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
            .build();
}
```

And the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JTOpenDataSourceConfiguration {

@Bean(name="distillerDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.distiller")
public DataSource distillerDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.target")
public DataSource targetDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("targetDataSource") DataSource targetDataSource) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(targetDataSource);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: in my case, if we write to repository it should be set transaction manager to chunk process, thanks @delewis