# Issue with configuring Atomikos on a Spring Boot / Spring Batch application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, distributed-transactions, atomikos, spring-cloud-task

I am trying to get Atomikos to work with my Spring Boot/Spring Batch application.

Here is are the relevant portions of my code:

Datasource config:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("batch_database")
    public DataSource batchDatasource() {
        return connectionFactory().dataSource("batch_database");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        return  new JtaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer configurer(){
        return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(batchDatasource());
    }
}
```

Atomikos auto-config dependency:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos")
```

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.application.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
spring.datasource.batch.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
```

Here is the auto-configuration report:

```
   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [batchDatasource, applicationDatasource, batch_database, application_database, database] (OnBeanCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration did not match
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager,com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [transactionManager] (OnBeanCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration.AtomikosJtaJmsConfiguration did not match
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.jms.Message (OnClassCondition)
      - Ancestor 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.AtomikosJtaConfiguration' did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
```

I am not sure why Atomikos is not auto-configured... Can anyone please help?

**edit**: I have commented out the JTA transactionManager bean and I now get the following auto-configuration report:

```
   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [batchDatasource, applicationDatasource, batch_database, application_database, database] (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary candidate amongst the following [transactionManager] (OnBeanCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration did not match
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager,com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [transactionManager] (OnBeanCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration.AtomikosJtaJmsConfiguration did not match
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.jms.Message (OnClassCondition)
      - Ancestor 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.AtomikosJtaConfiguration' did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
```

How can I make sure the Atomikos transaction manager is picked up?

**edit 2**: I have excluded `TransactionManager` classes as follows:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, TransactionAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but I seems that `SimpleBatchConfiguration` and `SimpleTaskConfiguration` still force one of several `TransactionManager` class(es) on me:

```
2016-07-12 11:27:57.846  INFO 4851 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration]
```

causing the `AtomikosJtaConfiguration` not to match...

Can someone please advise a best practice in order to get Atomikos auto-configuration to work?

Comment: Because you are adding your own `JtaTransactionManager` that disables the auto configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum: thanks. I have commented out the jta transaction manager but somehow a local transaction manager is picked up by spring boot...

Comment: I guess it is a slightly different question but how can I figure out where this `transactionManager` bean mentioned in the auto-configuration report comes from?

Comment: That is a different question, but that is answered in the report `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched` says it all.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821028/spring-boot-integration-with-spring-batch-and-jpa . I feel that this could be a similar 'type' of issue, maybe my answer in linked thread will give you some lead.

Comment: I am still not sure how to sort my original issue - which is actually a Spring Boot auto-configuration problem due to my current setup... Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add Atomikos or Bitronix to specify a PlatformTransactionManager for your datasource. See [Entities not persisting. Are RepositoryItemWriter & SimpleJpaWriter thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883470/entities-not-persisting-are-repositoryitemwriter-simplejpawriter-thread-safe/33885017#33885017).

Comment: Hi delewis.  According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820818, it seems the only way to have the job repository data and the application data in two different databases is to use XA/distributed transactions.

Comment: I am therefore not sure the persisting issue is related to thread safety.

Comment: My application has two data sources, as well, that read and write between each other as part of a batch job. Even though the post is referencing thread safety, the issue that I had with entities not persisting is similar to your's, and adding a PlatformTransactionManager to my data source and step beans addressed the issue.

Comment: I have a requirement for two databases (not just datasources).Do you think I can avoid distributed transactions ?

Comment: I have two databases, as well. My application does not utilize XA datasource, but I did find that entities would not persist unless I created a JpaTransactionManager like this (targetDataSource is my 1st database that I am reading from):     @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("targetDataSource") DataSource targetDataSource) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(targetDataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }

Comment: Then, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26882092/536299) - which states that one needs XA transactions in order to write to two different databases - might be incorrect?

Comment: You could use a form of [chained transaction manager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.java) but XA is the only way you can guarantee that either both writes succeed or they both fail, no matter what.

You can also refer to [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) - granted, it's old - but it still holds, not much has changed since then.