# Spring Batch multiple datasources and ChainedTransactionManager risks

Tags: spring-batch

I am doing a study on the feasibility of a Spring Batch composed of two datasources. A SQL datasource for the Spring Batch metadata and a MongoDB datasource (with transactional use) for the business data. The transactional aspect raises several questions here.

The following topic: [Spring batch with MongoDB and transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66425674/spring-batch-with-mongodb-and-transactions) and related resources provide a number of answers to my questions.
The answer mentions the use of Spring's `JtaTransactionManager` to manage distributed transactions on the two datasources.
This technique uses the 2PC protocol. It is also the most robust solution if I understood correctly. https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2

On the other hand, I found some resources about Spring's `ChainedTransactionManager`. This technique uses the best effort 1PC protocol. This solution is less robust, if I understand correctly the system can be in an inconsistent state in case of a problem in the infrastructure (network failure for example).
The `ChainedTransactionManager` has the advantage of being easier to implement and offers better performance. I saw that it is deprecated https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2232.

What are the concrete risks of using the `ChainedTransactionManager` in a Spring Batch? In case of an error, can I have inconsistencies between the Spring batch metadata and the business data in Mongo?
I imagine there are also considerations to take into account with retry or chunk skip strategies?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In case of an error, can I have inconsistencies between the Spring batch metadata and the business data in Mongo?

Yes, that's is the risk you should be aware of.

A common technique to avoid that is to disable state management and use the [process indicator pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator). You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#parallel-sample).